# Updating a Database Constantly Through an App, Not Efficient?

Tags: database, performance, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, memory-efficient

I need to update constantly a database, which is used by an app. The only link that I have to the database is through the app.

So the problem is that the update is about a lot of calculations about all the users' data and it might be a bit heavy, and I don't know if running this in the background of the app in someone's phone is really the most efficient way of doing it.

Is there a way to access and update the database constantly without rendering the efficiency of the app? Or maybe hosting the code in another place where it could run constantly? This way I wouldn't be using the user's phone resources to make all the calculations.

I'm using the Flutter SDK to make the app, and Firebase's Cloud Firestore as the database.

Comment: Does this help you https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database ?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is that you're trying to solve.  Is there some code that isn't working the way you expect?  If so, edit the question to show it and explain in more detail.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm trying to run, within the app, heavy calculations for a database. But I would be using the user's phone resources, and maybe that's not the most efficient way of doing it. I was wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, offload that work to a backend you control so it can complete without the user's participation.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need cloud functions. Where you would normally have a server to process data, you can create functions that run on demand with no servers to manage. It scales as per your needs, and you pay for what you use.

I personally find that Google Cloud Functions seem to work the best with Flutter, but all work.

The main 3 providers of these systems are:

[Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions)

[AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)

[Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/)

Answer (score 1):

Not with your exact setup, but I had to tackle a very similar problem some weeks ago.

In the end we modified the architecture, which was similar to yours:

```
app <==> database
```

The database actually only held three tables, but the customer requested the addition of several complicated historical statistics. The problem was that there was no way those statistics could be calculated "in real time" as requested (we came up with several solutions and *every time* a new feature was requested that exactly, carefully negated our setup).

In the end we added several more tables holding "current situation" and "last precalculated situation", so access to the "LPS" was really fast. And:

```
app <== database[LPS]
    ==> database[updates]  ===> 
        database[history]  ===>  big background app on another server 
        database[CS]       <===
```

The database was *also* accessed by another app on a cloud server, which moved the last updates into "acquired_updates", then worked those plus the history plus other data and precalculated the next point in time. Meanwhile, the users blithely accessed the previous version. When the CS is finished, we swap the table pointers so that from that moment onwards the accesses will be done on CS, freeing the LPS tables -- which can then be safely zapped and freed to become the next CS.

The whole calculation takes currently about eight minutes, so users see data with an average delay of four minutes. Since the data they enter are themselves time-skewed, this is no big deal; a coloured line on the top of the screen shows the time to next update.